# $ P\left(E_e\right)=\sum _{\eta =1}^{\mathbb{H}} P\left(H_{\eta }\right) P\left(E_e|H_{\eta }\right) $ How to prove?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, alternative-proof

Is it that true?

If yes, how to prove this?

$$
P\left(E_e\right)=\sum _{\eta =1}^{\mathbb{H}} P\left(H_{\eta
   }\right) P\left(E_e|H_{\eta }\right),
$$

where $E_e$ is an generic evidence, $H_\eta$ it's the $\eta$-esim hyphotesis and $\mathbb{H}$ is the cardinality of the hypothesis ($H$) set.

Comment: I don't quite follow the jargon, but the formula looks like the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: Looks like very simple yet...but didnt find a way until now. Thx about the link. I will take a look.

Comment: Just be aware that the law of total probability $P(A) = \sum_i P(A\mid B_i)P(B_i)$ assumes $A \subset \cup_i B_i \subset \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the entire sample space.  More simply, people just assume $\cup_i B_i = \Omega$ for simplicity.

Comment: @SrivatsanNarayanan, if one fo you answer this question, I will embrace it. Someone else too. I just don't want post my own answer.

Comment: @DilipSarwate if one fo you answer this question, I will embrace it. Someone else too. I just don't want post my own answer.

Comment: @GarouDan There's nothing wrong whatsoever with answering your own question! In fact, the site explicitly permits and encourages this. In any case, I already posted an answer this time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you quote seems to be just the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). Assume that the set of events $\{ H_\eta \}_{1 \leq \eta \leq \mathbb H}$ forms a partition of the sample space $\Omega$; i.e., the $H_\eta$'s are pairwise disjoint, and $\bigcup \limits_{\eta = 1}^{\mathbb H} H_\eta = \Omega$.

Now for any event $E_e$, the set of events $\{ E_e \cap H_\eta \}$ forms a partition of $E_e$. Therefore, by additivity, we have
$$
P(E_e) = \sum_{\eta = 1}^{\mathbb H} P(E_e \cap H_\eta). \tag{1}
$$
Now, by the definition of conditional probability, we have $P(E_e \cap H_\eta) = P(H_\eta) \cdot P(E_e \mid H_\eta)$. Plugging this in $(1)$ we get the claim.*

The following sentence taken from the wikipedia article explains what this theorem means intuitively (notation changed to match ours):

> The summation can be interpreted as a weighted average, and consequently the marginal probability, $P(E_e)$, is sometimes called "average probability"; "overall probability" is sometimes used in less formal writings.

---

*The formula is true even for $\{ H_\eta \}_{\eta \geq 1}$ forms a countably infinite partition of $\Omega$. The proof has to be modified only slightly for this.

Comment: Thx. A good answer!